# Flask Deployment to AWS getting permission errno 13

Tags: python-3.x, flask, amazon-ec2

I have working app on the localhost but when I deployed to the AWS it shows several errors.It can receive my sent image but it cant save it. I tried change permissions with chmod,still its not working. This is first time i am deploying flask app,so I dont know much about i My code is as follow:

```
***modules***

ImageFile.LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES = True

app = flask.Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods = ['GET','POST'])

def hello():
    return 'hey there!!!'


@app.route('/imageupload', methods = ['GET','POST'])

def handle_request():
    try:
        imagefile = flask.request.files['image']
        filename = werkzeug.utils.secure_filename(imagefile.filename)
        print("\nReceived image file name:" + imagefile.filename)
        imagefile.save(filename)
        print("hey")
        for image in glob.glob('./frames/*.*'):
            img_filter(imagefile,image)
        json = flask.request.values['Id']

        return {"status": "true","message": "Uploaded Successfully", "Id": json }


    except:
        return {"status" : "false"}

if __name__ == '__main__' :
    app.run()
```

And these are the errors :

```
Received image file name:1.jpg

ERROR:image_flask:Exception on /imageupload [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/ubuntu/pic-edit/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2446, in ws$
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "/home/ubuntu/pic-edit/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1951, in fu$
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "/home/ubuntu/pic-edit/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in ha$
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/home/ubuntu/pic-edit/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in $
raise value
File "/home/ubuntu/pic-edit/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1949, in fu$
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "/home/ubuntu/pic-edit/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1935, in di$
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "/var/www/html/pic-edit/image_flask.py", line 26, in handle_request
imagefile.save(f'/home/ubuntu/pic-edit/{filename}')
File "/home/ubuntu/pic-edit/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/datastructures.py", li$
dst = open(dst, "wb")
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/ubuntu/pic-edit/1.jpg'
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't have the right permission. Try to open first the folder with `chmod -R 700 /home/ubuntu/pic-edit/`
Please note open the permissions like this can be dangerous. Rather I would assign the permission to the "Flask" - Running user

Further for investigations under which user are you running the flask app? How do you start the app?

Also you might change the handle func to:

```
def handle_request():
    try:
        f = request.files['file']
        f.save(secure_filename(f.filename))
        json = flask.request.values['Id']

        return {"status": "true","message": "Uploaded Successfully", "Id": json }
```

note you nead to import `from flask import request`

Comment: i tried that its working but now this coming : (13)Permission denied: [client 123.136.198.61:48934] AH00035: access to /imageupload denied (filesystem path '/var/www/html$

Comment: ok why are you storing the files to /home/ubuntu which is the home folder from the ubuntu user but appearently not home from the user you are accessing. I would recommend to store it either at /srv (personal preference) or close to the application

Comment: alright i updated some stuff in my answer can you check, this should solve your problem

Comment: now i cant access the link : Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.

Comment: in which folder was it saved can you again try to change permissions of the folder to 700

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203763/discussion-between-amar-sagat-and-ghovat).

Answer (score 0):

I got it where I went wrong, that is because of permissions to the folder. I already tried "chmod 755" to it but it did not worked. After that I tried
    chmod a+rwx
And that work fluently.